# Counterpart to std::enable_if_t

Tags: c++14, template-meta-programming, type-traits, decltype, enable-if

`std::enable_if_t` gets you a type if a certain value is true. Now I want a thing that gets you a type if an expression is well-formed. If the type I want is `void`, I can do `decltype((void)(expr))`. But what should I do if I want something other than `void`? I want an succinct and elegant solution.

Comment: Are you trying to implement something like [`std::experimental::is_detected`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/is_detected)? Maybe you want something like [`std::void_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/void_t).

Comment: `decltype((void)(expr), std::declval<the_type_you_want>())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct well_formed : std::true_type{};
```

And then combine that with `enable_if_t`

Comment: If `T` is not well-formed, then the entire expression fails to compile instead of returning `false_type`.  So it isn't well named...  You might as well do `std::conditional_t< false, decltype(expr), result_type >`

Comment: @Yakk `std::enable_if_t<well_formed<expr>::value, result_type>` is pretty clear, though, I think. I like you version too, especially since you do not need another helper struct, but I believe it is a bit harder to read.

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear exactly how you want to use this, but you could generalise `std::void_t`:

```
template<typename T, typename...> struct helper { using type = T; };
template<typename T, typename...Ts> 
using type_t = typename helper<T,Ts...>::type;
```

(The helper may be needed due to [this standards defect](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1558))

Then use it like so:

```
type_t<int, decltype(expr)>
```